# Select statement PDO error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$orderby = 'title';
$order = 'ASC';

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT f.id, title, description, release_year, first_name, last_name FROM film AS f, film_actor AS fa JOIN actor AS a WHERE fa.actor_id = a.actor_id AND fa.film_id = f.film_id ORDER BY :orderby :order LIMIT :limit');
$stmt->execute(
    array(  'order'=>$order, 
            'orderby'=>$orderby, 
            'limit'=>$limit
        )
    );
```

I'm getting the error described in the title when trying to run this query. I've tried to find a way to debug the output but failed. I'll appreciate the help.
PS: I'm learning SQL using PDO in PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `:` here

```
array(  'order'=>$order, 
        'orderby'=>$orderby, 
        'limit'=>$limit
    )
```

should be

```
array(  ':order'=>$order, 
        ':orderby'=>$orderby, 
        ':limit'=>$limit
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, i've made that change but I still get the same error.
Here's the corrected code:
`$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT f.id, title, description, release_year, first_name, last_name FROM film AS f, film_actor AS fa JOIN actor AS a WHERE fa.actor_id = a.actor_id AND fa.film_id = f.film_id ORDER BY :orderby :order LIMIT :limit');
$stmt->execute(
array( ':order'=>$order, 
        ':orderby'=>$orderby, 
 ':limit'=>$limit)
  );`

Comment: @talentedunicorn show the full error.

Comment: Here's the full error:
`DB Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''200'' at line 1`

Comment: @talentedunicorn where you have assigned `200` in your query? I can't see it.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, i think 200 is `limit` because he forgot to put `,` between two `order by` columns

Comment: Oh yeah sorry guys there was a variable `$limit = 200;` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $stmt->execute() will add quotes around the $limit value hence 200 will be '200' resulting to an error.

A suggested solution is to use bindParam() 
Look here for more info http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php